# Moving an uploaded file using PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

please could someone check this for me?  I have followed the info that I found on here and still I cant get it to work.  My host says that this should now be possible as the permissions were previously blocked, and are not exactly the most helpful.
Thanks, I can always rely on StackOverflow to help out when needed.  :)

```
<?PHP
IF(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $caption = $_POST['caption'];
    $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $target="images/slider";
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'images/slider/'.$_FILES['file']['name']) or die ('cannot upload');

    require_once('../includes/dbupcombo.php');

        $query = "INSERT INTO PremierSlider (caption, image) values ('$caption','$file')";
        mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


}
header("location: http://www.premierdancecentre.com/admin/index.php#mod_image");
}
?>
```

The script runs onclick and returns 'cannot upload'.  Any help as to why would be greatly appreciated as i'm still trying to get good at PHP.  Cheers guys

Comment: make sure the directory exists there

Comment: In PHP, there is a way to check what's wrong when a file upload fails using $_FILES['file']['error']. Try printing the error and post here what error code you are getting. Details here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }


?>
```

Comment: You may want to be wary with printing out details like filename, since it could contain virtually anything. It would also be worth putting uploaded files outside the document root.

Comment: better to check `if ($_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)` from a pedantic point of view. Nothing says the PHP maintainers can't go insane later and redefine an 'ok' upload as 255 or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

First of all please check that you are using a proper form tag

`<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">`

check that you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on form.

in `upload_file.php`

check that you are really getting the file by doing

`var_dump($_FILES)`

if yes, then you can use your `move_uploaded_file`