# naming a file after submitting a form in Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.5

I am working on a form which accepts some user input and an image file, the submission part and the data getting entered into the database is working fine but I am stuck at how to name a file once it is uploaded, right now this is what i see as an image name in database `C:\wamp2.5\tmp\phpF360.tmp` which obviously is not correct.

This is what my controller looks like `DefaultController.php`

```
public function createBlogAction(Request $request)
{

    $post = new Post();
    $form = $this->createForm(new PostCreate(), $post);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $post->upload();
        $post->setDate(date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
        $post->setAuthor('ClickTeck');
        $em->persist($post);
        $em->flush();

        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
            'notice',
            'Success'
        );
    }

    return $this->render('BlogBundle:Default:blog-create.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        )
    );
}
```

This is what my `upload()` looks like inside `Entity/Post.php` which is uploading the file and moving it into the folder, the file name that I see in a folder is correct however now the one that goes into the database

```
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->getImage()) {
        return;
    }

    // I might be wrong, but I feel it is here that i need to name the file
    $this->getImage()->move(
        $this->getUploadRootDir(),
        $this->getImage()->getClientOriginalName()
    );

    $this->path = $this->getUploadDir();
    $this->file = null;
}
```

I will really appreciate if someone can push me in right direction, I just need to name the file, a name which gets assigned to the image in database and the file should get uploaded with the same name as well.

---

**UPDATE**

I managed to get it to work using the following function, not sure if this is the best practice but it did work, i would love to hear from others on this. please do not provide any links, if you can refine what has already been done that would be great.

```
public function upload()
{
    // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
    if (null === $this->getImage()) {
        return;
    }
    $dirpath = $this->getUploadRootDir();
    $image = $this->getImage()->getClientOriginalName();
    $ext = $this->getImage()->guessExtension();
    $name = substr($image, 0, - strlen($ext));
    $i = 1;
    while(file_exists($dirpath . '/' .  $image)) {
        $image = $name . '-' . $i .'.'. $ext;
        $i++;
    }
    $this->getImage()->move($dirpath,$image);
    $this->image = $image;
    $this->path = $this->getUploadDir();
    $this->file = null;
}
```

Comment: [function.move-uploaded-file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) is normally used to transfer and rename the 'temporary' uploaded file to somewhere permanent. An example: [questions/6179178/moving-an-uploaded-file-using-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179178/moving-an-uploaded-file-using-php).

Comment: I find your question unclear:

"the submission part and the data getting entered into the database is working fine but I am stuck at how to name a file once it is uploaded"

"the file name that I see in a folder is correct however now the one that goes into the database"

That's rather contradictory isn't ?

What's that function move() ? as pointed by Ryan Vincent, php function is not this one.

Comment: @Eagle1 what i mean is i can get the image uploaded just fine and the file name and path is being inserted into database just fine as well, if is the name of file that i am having the problem with, the name that gets saved is like `:\wamp2.5\tmp\phpF360.tmp` rather than `nameofimage.jpg`

Comment: i am strictly following http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html, i dont think i am using parts of both

Answer (score 1):

This topic from documentation may help you : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

In addition, you should not put your upload function in the controller but rather use Doctrine events (Lifecycle callbacks) to call your function automatically.

Comment: Ya i have already gone through this documentation couple of times, eventually the controller will be as thin as possible but since i am in my learning mode i just wanted to get it to work and then put everything where it should be

Comment: just so it is clear the upload function is not inside the controller it is inside the `Entity/Post.php` file which is making use of Doctrine

Answer (score 0):

as per suggestion of @theofabry you can check symfony2 documentation [How to handle File Uploads with Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html), Controller must be thin as much as possible and try to do upload with `Doctrine Events`.

If you want to continue with your logic you may try following code, I have not tested yet...so please be careful.

```
   // set the path property to the filename where you'ved saved the file
   $this->path = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();
```

instead of

```
 $this->path = $this->getUploadDir();
```

Comment: ya i know and i agree with you about the controller, this is not how the controller is going look eventually but just for the sake of getting the document named correctly i tried what you mentioned, both of them work find for the image path but not the image name

Comment: just so it is clear the upload function is not inside the controller it is inside the `Entity/Post.php` file which is making use of Doctrine